# Free body diagrams for dummies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, free-body-diagram, education

I'm self-studying physics. What are some good books/online resources to practice making free body diagrams for learning classical mechanics?

Comment: Is there a specific question you have about them?

Comment: I'm not that good at them, and I just need practice. For example, I was just looking at a question about some blocks on a frictionless surface of different sizes (10kg, 5kg, etc) and ropes between them, and then the question is how much tension is between each rope if the front block is being pulled with, say, 20N. That sort of thing.

Comment: You have to visualize all the forces acting on each body and _where_ these forces are. Gravity is always on the center of mass, and contact forces are always through the contact point and along the contact normal. Tangent to contacts is friction and if a value ends up being calculated negative, then flip the direction of that force to make it positive.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what do you mean by "dummies". But in my opinion Introduction to Classical Mechanics(by David Morin) is a good book with a complete chapter dedicated to it. I would suggest you to give time to problems even if you find them hard or undoable.

If not that, probably Resnick Haliday or University Physics are good for some introductory problems.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following YouTube playlist by prof.
Michel van Biezen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbMVOzP2SjM&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen.

It consists of ten rather short videos where step by step FBD's are done.

I found this professor's channel to be quite useful, and if I ever needed more practice or clarification on a topic, I'd often check there.